# pysnmp send request not working

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, pysnmp

I am new to network programming specifically to snmp. I just want to send a simple snmp request localy and see what it gives out. so far the documentation does not really say much about the send method. This what I followed as [example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/pysnmp-hlapi-tutorial.html) and [this](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/advanced-topics.html). I first used them as there are but later customized them like for instance below:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
g = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
CommunityData('public'),
UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
ContextData(),
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('TCP-MIB', 'tcpConnectionState',
                         'ipv4', '127.0.0.1', 41511,
                         'ipv4', '127.0.0.1', 993)
)
)
g.send([ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifInOctets'))])
```

However I am getting this error:

TypeError: can't send non-None value to a just-started generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to send a value to *Python generator* rather than to your peer SNMP agent. Just use `next()` instead (or put that generator it into a loop) so it will push SNMP packet out to the network on the first iteration. Here is the [example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/snmp-versions.html#snmpv2c).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now what I am not getting is how I could specify the type of information I want. For instance arp table information

Comment: In general, that depends on the kind of SNMP device you are talking to. You may try wakling the `BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dTpFdbTable` (which is 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3).

Comment: Thanks again. It did work. Do you know any good documentation for it. I am getting mac addresses but I can't recognize the IP addesses. They are supposed to be included in the OID response but look completely different they now like 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.x.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx. Is there any way to get ip addresses too?

Comment: @user4237435 it is quite unusual that you have to extract values (such as IPs) from OID rather than querying specific OID for the value you need. Are you sure your MIB does not offer MIB object that lets you do `GET OID -> IP`? If not, you mention your response OID embeds an IP you need -- could you take it from there?

Comment: @IIya Etingof The main idea is to get the match between ip and mac address. That is normally arp table shows ip and mac correspondance. What I got as snmp response is something that I did not expect. For an ip like 192.168.1.1 with a mac like 0xVNXXYYDDZZLL, I get something like SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.1.17.4.3.x.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx = 0xVNXXYYDDZZLL with no value from the expected 192.168.1.1

Comment: @IIya Etingof  I just got to know the value x.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx is no ip address. That is the mac address is decimal. Meaning that the OID is actually not giving the ip address for corresponding mac address

Comment: @user4237435 I am now thinking you may be hitting [this](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/54) issue. If you still need to resolve it, I'd suggest you filing more details into that pysnmp issue (or open a new one). A reproducer would be especially helpful!